# python discriminate between references and equations with regex in text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove all the references in a piece of text- they are contained in brackets. Hence the easiest thing to do would be to remove everything in brackets unanimously... But somethings in brackets are important such as equations...
So I suppose that I could remove all brackets costing '*et al.*' but not all references have an et al in them....
Can anyone tell me who to use python expressions to distinguish between equations and reference that are specified in the format '**(Author [possible et al.], year)**'

example to unanimously remove bracket contained content:

```
file=open("polymer_model.txt", "r")
mystring = file.read()
def a(test_str):
    ret = ''
    skip = 0
    for i in test_str:
        if i == '(':
            skip += 1
        elif i == ')'and skip2c > 0:
            skip -= 1
        elif skip == 0:
            ret += i
    return ret


x = a(mystring)
```

example of attempt to remove all bracket contained content where an "et al: is included:

```
x=re.sub(r'(\w+ et al.\)s?','',x)
```

> It is assumed that the average twisting energy is equal to **(1/2)kT**
>   , we also have **Teff = (C/kl).(rmsd(Tw))2** (Munteanu et al., 1998; Olson, 1996; Olson and Zhurkin, 2000). However this model is somewhat rudimentary according to other studies which prefer the equation: **w∝exp(−E/kT)** (Schlick, 1995)

Should be:

> It is assumed that the average twisting energy is equal to (1/2)kT , we also have Teff = (C/kl).(rmsd(Tw))2. However this model is somewhat rudimentary according to other studies which prefer the equation: w∝exp(−E/kT)

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I'm still not exactly clear what you want to remove and what you want to keep.

Comment: edited to give an example of the code i'm using

Comment: we can't tell you how to use python to do this until you can tell a human how to do this. What is the criteria you are using to decide what gets removed and what doesn't? For example, will the data to be removed always end with a four digit year?

Comment: would a comma ever appear in an equation? all citations contain at least one comma, so you could just exploit that detail.

Comment: Hi Tadhg, thanks no a comma or semicolon would never appear in an equation

Comment: linsung yes exactly all citations are in the form , yyyy). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following regex:

```
\([A-Z]\w+[^\)]+?, (18|19|20)[0-9]{2}\)
```

- **\(** the bracket char
- **[A-Z]** Author should start with a capitale letter
- **\w+** rest of the authors name
- **[^\)]+?** everything else except a closing bracket
- **, (19|20)[0-9]{2}** comma, followed by the year. If you have books released before 1900 you have to add the years
- **\)** the bracket char

But its only a good guess. There could be a formular that matches this regex or an quotation that will not be matched. But I think the `, year`-Part should do it in most cases.

You can try here more examples:
https://regex101.com/r/AKmfdr/2

Comment: is `[^\)]+?` the same as `[^\)]*` ?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen no. + means at least one and the ? tells the regex to be lazy and not greedy: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: (checks reference) `?` is not independent of the `+` That was my mistake. Thanks for the clarification.